# MySQL - Statistics per ip

Tags: mysql

I'm unable to found a way to get some statistics per IP since the server started.

I would like to get a count of queries executed by IP address. The goal is to check if a server is abnormally using our database.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't find any documentation related this feature of mysql.

Maybe you can obtain this information in another way. I think two possible solutions:

1. Enable general query log(http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-log.html) and parse/analize this log. Enabling this log could be reduce the performance of your system.
2. Using "Linux Network IP Accounting" (if you use linux) you can try to count the number of tcp packet coming from different ip to port 3306 of your server. But these information could be less interesting and useful compared to the mysql general query log